# Type declaring destructured objects in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a re-usable custom hook that enables a user close the menu when they either click off the node or press escape.

I've never used Typescript before and I want to destructure the event object rather than use it directly, e.g. `event.type`, and create type declarations for the object keys.

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IProps {
  type: React.MouseEvent<string> | React.KeyboardEvent<string>;
  target: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>;
  key?: React.KeyboardEvent<string>;
}

/**
 * Allows you to close a menu when user clicks outside of the nodes family tree.
 */
function useCloseMenu(
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<any>,
  isMenuOpen: boolean,
  callback: () => void
): void {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleUserEvent({ type, target, key = null }: IProps): void {
      switch (type) {
        case "click":
          if (!ref.current?.contains(target) && isMenuOpen) {
            callback();
          }

        case "keydown":
          // "Esc" is an IE/Edge specific value
          if (key === ("Escape" || "Esc") && isMenuOpen) {
            callback();
          }
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
    };
  }, [isMenuOpen]);
}

export default useCloseMenu;
```

```
use-close-menu.tsx:21:14 - error TS2678: Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'MouseEvent<string, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<string>'.

21         case "click":
                ~~~~~~~

use-close-menu.tsx:26:14 - error TS2678: Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'MouseEvent<string, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<string>'.

26         case "keydown":
                ~~~~~~~~~

use-close-menu.tsx:28:15 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'KeyboardEvent<string>' and 'string' have no overlap.

28           if (key === ("Escape" || "Esc") && isMenuOpen) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

use-close-menu.tsx:34:40 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "click", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<string, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters '__0' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<string, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<string>'.

34     document.addEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


use-close-menu.tsx:35:42 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown", listener: (this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'KeyboardEvent' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<string, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

35     document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


use-close-menu.tsx:37:45 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "click", listener: (this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to type 'IProps'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

37       document.removeEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


use-close-menu.tsx:38:44 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown", listener: (this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '({ type, target, key }: IProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

38       document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Found 7 errors.
```

However, I'm going round in circles with TS error handling here. Can someone help me understand how to resolve these errors?

Comment: `type` is an event object, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone help me understand how to resolve these errors?

tl;dr - `key` property does not exist on the `MouseEvent`.

Personally I'd remove `IProps` completely and just pass whole `event` object to the `handleUserEvent` function. Then, we could implement a `type guard` to check wheter the current event is `mouse` or `keyboard`.

```
import React from 'react';

type Evt = KeyboardEvent | MouseEvent;

function isKeyboardEvent(event: Evt): event is KeyboardEvent {
  return 'key' in event;
}

function useCloseMenu(
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<any>,
  isMenuOpen: boolean,
  callback: () => void
): void {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleUserEvent(event: Evt): void {
        const { type, target } = event;

      switch (type) {
        case "click":
          if (!ref.current?.contains(target) && isMenuOpen) {
            callback();
          }

        case "keydown":
          if (isKeyboardEvent(event) && event.key === ("Escape" || "Esc") && isMenuOpen) {
            callback();
          }
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleUserEvent);
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserEvent);
    };
  }, [isMenuOpen]);
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFEA3eAXjgGklqAjCFKABNmSAHbwAPnACyEAK4BnJCPEVymOaIzAIouMAVde-ISpgAKJEzEwAXIxYBKe1Zv6FnbnwHDr4uADe5HBwRDByUHr4ANbc+Pp6rqrkAL6UGlowOnqKSADCADYQStJicubBoUiY9sjoMAB00nIwKDwFSMiYAPI8AFZIGAA8KKLUAHwANJUGpaJy3XSi9nwQHaPTIWgoBQU86NH25o5wrONwTBDAguTOF1eCgZV1GA25DJiYgxbHp+dBIRCGW0ujgAAtRoIOgBVJRQMyWPx2BwwO6Xa5PQFYuBoXQKeABOA0OiTIkCADmSHgKVOcCSMDU2LgCgA7sAYGgwXBzMSkCcAUycSglHAAERoArANDRUW2SqC-SYbkAQiImAaaAiRHEAH4NbpWsBRAoeRSqScAGQW9xzBZLfnyhVC3b7aXHChOuBpR1Y7Yi0WxaiCCAs0Syn3Y4BK8wGIzeUxIxE2S3W+kNQOnVjscyihgKbZ0UVwCRSXP50Upm1lRZiB2erY7PYHd0RrFpJntwHerHBzUgGwNFCCXw2AAyBhgYiQUBzEqlMtJENEUKQsOnZkcHsBvbk-fEg+HZnH+KnM4D3GDodFi8hMLhG63ITCET0vzOmOxO73jSIIAg1iPCdT1nSVpWvcFb1Xe8kU3CMvwHIcR3EY9J1Eacc0DS8wxvZc73XGDHy9LcUlJABtWZqyWABdWCUiAA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is helpful and interesting to see how you have helped to resolve the earlier errors but how would you also resolve the latter ones related to the `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Dan My bad - posted wrong code and link. Updated answer.

Comment: I also think it's worth mentioning that `document.addEventListener` simply doesn't accept a function with the custom `IProps` interface as a parameter. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) explains what the callback (`handleUserEvent` in this case) should look like.

Comment: Thanks this works and certainly helps my understanding.